# How to send a transaction with large data ethereum?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to send an array of object (tuple) to smart contract.

```
function addManyUsers (User [] memory _users) public {

        for (uint i = 0; i < _users.length; i++) {

           bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(_users[i].name));
           users[hash] = _users[i];

        }
    }
```

I have web3js v1.0.0-beta.37, I tried with websocket provider:

I got this error:

```
Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node on WS.
```

Then I tried with http provider, I got this error:

```
Error: Returned error: oversized data
```

I think there a data size limit, but can we upgrade that limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is a data size limit. you can check it in geth code 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/rpc/http.go

you'll find :

```
const (
    maxRequestContentLength = 1024 * 512
    contentType             = "application/json"
)
```

I think to rise it and recompile or better in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go
try to rise the transaction size

```
if tx.Size() > 32*1024 {
    return ErrOversizedData
}
```

Comment: is this the best solution ?, there no way to solve the problem without changing the code source ?

Comment: @maroodb AFAIK this is the only way (suitable for private chains) as this measure intends to protect the network against Dos attakcs